# Ruby loop and array

Tags: arrays, ruby

I've been trying to teach myself Ruby. I've found a few code problems to try solving, but I'm stuck. Here is what I have and the problems I'm trying to solve.

My algorithm is as follows:

- Prompt the user to enter a number between 1 and 10 (inclusive).
- Read that number into an appropriately named variable.
- Test that the number lies in the appropriate range.
- Input new number if it is out of bounds as per the condition.
- Use the number entered by the user to create an array with that
  number of elements.
- Write a loop which will run through a number of iterations equal to
  the size of the array.
- Each time through, prompt the user to enter a text string - a name
  (names of cars, that sort of thing).
- Once the array is entered, display the contents of the array three
  items to a line.

You will want a for loop for this, and within the for loop you should include a decision which will insert a line break at the appropriate places.

Also,

- Separate the array elements with dashes - but do not put a dash
  before the first element on a line, and do not put a dash after the
  last element on a line.
- Use a Ruby function to sort the array alphabetically, then display it
  again, the same way as before.
- Reverse the order of the array

Display its contents a third time, again putting three elements on each line of output and placing dashes the way you did with the first display effort.

```
loop do
    print "Enter an integer between 1 and 10: "
    s = gets.chomp.to_i
    if s >0 && s <= 10
        break
        else
        puts "Interger entered is outside specified range."
    end 
end
array=[]
array.size
loop do
    print "Enter name of a car model: "
    car=gets.chomp
    array<<car
    for i in array
        array.slice(1..9) {|car|
        puts car.join(", ")
        }
    end 
end
```

Comment: loop do
 print "Enter an integer between 1 and 10: "
 s = gets.chomp.to_i
 if s >0 && s <= 10
  break
  else
  puts "Interger entered is outside specified range."
 end 
end
array=[]
array.size
loop do
 print "Enter name of a car model: "
 car=gets.chomp
 array<<car
 for i in array
  array.slice(1..9) {|car|
  puts car.join(", ")
  }
 end 
end

Comment: FYI, no one wants to read that much text.

Comment: You forgot to describe the problem you're experiencing.

Comment: When I enter a car model, the loop continues until I use Ctrl+C. and it is not outputting the desired array 3 elements per line.

Comment: There are several problems with your code.  I suggest breaking down your large problem into smaller ones.  Verify that the first loop works before proceeding...and so on.  Your loops have problems regarding exit conditions.  Check out `(1..10).include?(...)` as a better idiom for number range inclusion tests. The `array.size` line has no effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is that solution you looking for?

```
loop do
  print "Enter an integer between 1 and 10: "
  s = gets.chomp.to_i

  if (1..10).include?(s)
    arr = [""] * s
    i = 0
    while i < arr.length
      print "Enter name of a car model: "
      car = gets.chomp
      arr[i] = car
      i += 1
    end

    puts arr.join(", ")
    break
  else
    puts "Interger entered is outside specified range."
    break
  end
end
```

Result is:

```
[retgoat@iMac-Roman ~/temp]$ ruby loop.rb
Enter an integer between 1 and 10: 2
Enter name of a car model: car_a
Enter name of a car model: car_b
car_a, car_b
```

**UPDATE**

Below solution to print an array by 3 elements per line with natural sorting

```
loop do
  print "Enter an integer between 1 and 10: "
  s = gets.chomp.to_i

  if (1..10).include?(s)
    arr = [""] * s
    i = 0
    while i < arr.length
      print "Enter name of a car model: "
      car = gets.chomp
      arr[i] = car
      i += 1
    end

    puts arr.sort.each_slice(3){ |e| puts "#{e.join(", ")}\n"}
    break
  else
    puts "Interger entered is outside specified range."
    break
  end
end
```

Result is:

```
[retgoat@iMac-Roman ~/temp]$ ruby loop.rb
Enter an integer between 1 and 10: 4
Enter name of a car model: z
Enter name of a car model: a
Enter name of a car model: x
Enter name of a car model: b
a, b, x
z
```

And reverse sorting:

```
loop do
  print "Enter an integer between 1 and 10: "
  s = gets.chomp.to_i

  if (1..10).include?(s)
    arr = [""] * s
    i = 0
    while i < arr.length
      print "Enter name of a car model: "
      car = gets.chomp
      arr[i] = car
      i += 1
    end

    puts arr.sort{ |x, y| y <=> x }.each_slice(3){ |e| puts "#{e.join(", ")}\n"}
    break
  else
    puts "Interger entered is outside specified range."
    break
  end
end
```

Result is:

```
[retgoat@iMac-Roman ~/temp]$ ruby loop.rb
Enter an integer between 1 and 10: 4
Enter name of a car model: z
Enter name of a car model: a
Enter name of a car model: x
Enter name of a car model: b
z, x, b
a
```

Comment: This is getting closer. I need to output 3 elements per line. If i have 7 elements it should output on 3 lines with the first 2 lines having three elements and the 3rd line with one element.

Comment: To do this the directions state to use a for loop. I figured out how to add the dashes in place of the comma. Then I need to sort and output it in alphabetical order, and then reverse the order.

Comment: Using a `for` loop is discouraged in Ruby, there are so many better ways to accomplish the same thing.  See https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide and search the page for 'do not use for'.

Answer (score 1):

It's better to split you program into small pieces. Also, try not to use loop without necessity.

```
# Specify Exception class for your context
class ValidationException < RuntimeError
end

def number_of_cars_from_input
  # Get user input
  print 'Enter an integer between 1 and 10: '
  number = gets.chomp.to_i
  # Validate input for your requirements
  unless (1..10).cover?(number)
    raise ValidationException, 'Interger entered is outside specified range.'
  end
  number
rescue ValidationException => err
  # Print exception and retry current method
  puts err
  retry
end

# Get car name from user input
def car_from_input
  print 'Enter name of a car model: '
  gets.chomp
end

# Create array with size equal to number from imput and fill it with cars
array_of_cars = Array.new(number_of_cars_from_input) { car_from_input }
# Separate cars in groups by 3 and join groups
puts array_of_cars.each_slice(3).map { |a| a.join(', ') }
```